# How can I remove a Google Analytics property from an organisation?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a clients Google Analytics property in my organisation somehow (definitely something I did).  I can't find a way to remove the property from my organisation back to having no organisation.

I don't really understand what organisations do but it's a little annoying that it has tied the two properties together when I look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unlink a product account, you need to be an admin for the product you're unlinking.

Sign in to Google Marketing Platform.
Click Administration > Organizations.
Click the relevant organization.
In Products, click the type of account you want to unlink (e.g., Analytics).
In the row for the specific account, click More, then click Unlink account.

Comment: Months I looked for that!  Excellent job, if I could award more points I would do!!!