# Extract organization from GA, old job

Tags: google-analytics, accounts

Attempting to use google analytics for a personal project and having issues..

I have a Google Analytics account that's using my personal gmail account. It was given access to a certain "organization" (from my old job) and it seems impossible to extract my account from it.

I'm unable to "move out of the organization" from the marketing platform since there's no other organization for me to go to.

I can't seem to just remove my user in the Admin > Account > Account Permissions since I don't seem to have access to myself?

This organization seems to creep into everything, including the "platform" popup at the top of the screen. I'd like my account to be completely separate and never have to look at the name of this company anymore.

I thought [unlinking a product](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/how-can-i-remove-a-google-analytics-property-from-an-organisation) would be the thing but that doesn't seem relevant since I don't even *have* a product.

any help is appreciated,